# reSIProcate Fatal error "FdPollItem idx=13 not deleted prior to destruction"

Tags: android, adb, logcat

There was a problem recently that my phone just restarts randomly when it connects to wifi, So I use adb logcat to catch the error and this is what I got:

```
07-12 15:07:34.341  3190  3337 F reSIProcate: CRIT | RESIP | FdPoll.cxx:551 | FdPollItem idx=13 not deleted prior to destruction
```

a few minutes after that I got this:

```
07-12 15:10:20.322 31035 31035 F OIC_SRM_DOXM: UpdatePersistentStorage failed!
```

*I don't know if it's related or not*

What can I do about this error?